# Проблема при считывании файла

Tags: c#

Есть файл docx. В нем лежит таблица обычная.

Я пытаюсь печатать файл и сразу сохраняю файл предварительного просмотра. и там лежит битые данные что то типо:
PK ! lT [Content_Types].xml  ( j0 E6J(ɢe h 4NDeIh&8NC)i M133
£x]l m }X?+9 F @1] *c)D^Js !J R_LF?
M +u rj<h Z8ʞ%IPd mcU
Z қ*).` 6b <T ^h5

Вот код, что я е так делаю:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
        printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings = printDialog1.PrinterSettings;
        printDocument1.Print();

    }

    void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader TF = new StreamReader(@"C:\TemplateMail.docx", Encoding.UTF8);
        string TFF = TF.ReadToEnd();
        TF.Dispose();

        var temp = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TemplateMail.docx");

        e.Graphics.DrawString(temp, Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(20, 20, 800, 600));
    }
```

Comment: Т.е. вы пытаетесь читать docx как обычный текстовый файл? Сильно!

Comment: А как правильно сделать?

Comment: Не уверен, что это решит проблему, но чтение pdf обеспечит (наверное) https://stackoverflow.com/a/7985501/17025310

Comment: Либо создать OLE объект `Word` и попросить его напечатать документ, либо вызвать `Process.Start(
ProcessStartInfo)` с установленным `Verb = "print"`. Либо написать свой парсер docx

Comment: Хорошо, всем спасибо, попробую